# Use function for each span element in jquery

Tags: jquery, class, hide, show, html

This is my css and Jquery i created this two functions to show text when an image in a table is clicked, then if the text is clicked it shows the image again.

```
<style>
.espanto {
    margin:0px 25px 0px 25px;
    display:none;
}

</style>
  <script>
function showImage(){
                $('.espanto').show();
                $('.hide').hide();
            }
            function hidonio(){
                $('.espanto').hide();
                $('.hide').show();
            }
</script>
```

Then i have this structure. here is where i coded the table and use the classes to make it happen

```
  <div id="content">
    <p align="center"><span class="titles" style="color:#1A4487; line-height:10px;">Productos Artesanales Gourmet</span></p>
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <p class="parag" style="  ">Kanaan le ofrece una extensa seleccion de conservas, chutneys, aceites y salsas, que le brindaran ese sabor que usted estaba buscando, por favor no dude en contactarnos si desea una cotizacion o muestras gratis, de clic en alguna imagen para ver su descripcion.</p>
    <p align="center"><span class="titles espanto" style="color:#1A4487; line-height:10px;"><br />
      Descripciones.</span></p>
    <table align="center" style="color:#1A4487;" width="650" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td width="250px"><p class="titles" align="center" > <span class="parag espanto"><br />
             <a href="#" onclick="hidonio()" >Producto de origen Hindú que sirve para acompañar y hornear carnes como pescado, pollo, cerdo, etc. Dándole un exquisito sabor a sus platillos, sabores: ciruela, tamarindo, carambolo, calabaza,  durazno y piña</a></span><a href="#" onclick="showImage()" ><img src="pr/Chutneys 2.jpg" height="200" class="hide" /></a><br />
            Chutneys</p></td>
        <td width="250px"><p class="titles" align="center"><span class="parag espanto"><br />
            <a href="#" onclick="hidonio()" > Aceites aderezados para saborizar carne y ensaladas de sabor canela, romero, laurel, thai, (rojo y picante), y hiervas finas</a></span><a href="#" onclick="showImage()" ><img src="pr/Aceites 2 a.jpg" height="200" class="hide"/></a><br />
            Aceites </p></td>
        <td width="250px"><p class="titles" align="center"> <span class="parag espanto"><br />
             <a href="#" onclick="hidonio()" >Conservas dulces (frutas en almíbar)<br />
            De todo tipo de frutas (guayaba, mango, durazno, piña, camote, calabaza, etc.)<br />
            <br />
            Conservas saladas (encurtidos)
            En salmuera o en vinagre (col morada, calabacita, espárragos, chichar
```

Comment: include the whole markup so we can help

Comment: `$('.titles').each(showImage)`?

Comment: You might want to change `.children('.hide')` to `.find('.hide')`.  `.hide` isn't a direct child of `.titles`.

Comment: I added the whole code. :) Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should follow the jQuery approach of unobtrusive JavaScript and avoid inline functions and   onclick handlers.

Instead use a selector to define a click event on your element like this:

```
$('.titles a:first').on('click', function(){
  $(this).closest('p').find('.espanto').hide();
  $(this).closest('p').find('.hide').show();
});
```

This is basically your first scenario. The second will work analogical with `$('.titles a:last')...`.

Have a look at the jQuery documentation for [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/), [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) and [traversing](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/)

---

**Update**

Here is a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EqG63/1/) that should do what you want. The code above is not completely working, especially the selector is false to get the links. Here is the update from the fiddle:

```
$('table td').find('a:first').on('click', function(){
    $(this)
        .parent()
            .hide()
        .parent().find('img').show();
}).end()
    .find('a:last').on('click', function(){
        $(this).hide()
            .closest('td').find('span:first').show();
    });​
```

Comment: will this work just for the first item? i have tried and it still hide and show all the items. :(